# Unresolved reference error in PyCharm, even though code runs ok

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running PyCharm 2019.2 on Ubuntu, with a project using Python 2. I have the following directory structure for my code:

```
Code
|____Common
     |____utils.py
|____Testing
     |____test.py
```

In `test.py`, I want to import `utils.py`. So, I simply have the line `from Common import utils` at the top of `test.py`.

This gave me the following error:

`No module named Common`

After reading up on this problem, I did two things. First, I added my Code directory to the Sources Root. Second, I added an `__init__.py` file to the Common directory. After doing this, the error went away.

So, it seems that Python 2 requires you to explicitly mark a directory as a package (using `__init__.py`) if you want to import one of its files as a module

But my question is as follows. In PyCharm, there is a red line underneath `utils` in the line `from Common import utils`. And when hovering over this, the message is: `Unresolved reference 'utils'`. This happens despite the fact that my code can run fine.

Why do I receive this error message telling me that there is an unresolved reference, when PyCharm is in fact able to find this reference?

---

UPDATE:

I have also tried running `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`. But upon restarting, there is still the red underline.

Comment: Pycharm's python path wasn't updated with the package - possible reason

Comment: Could you please expand the project tree and take a screenshot?

Answer (score -1):

Since it works, it seems that the problem is related with the GUI your are using.. I'd check the local paths that your code editor looks into (e.g. PYTHONPATH in Spyder GUI). Hope it solves your problem.